# Square bracket notation not working to get object property?

Tags: javascript, object, ag-grid, brackets, notation

Within Ag-Grid, I am using valueGetter to get values from multiple child columns for a parent column. Each child column has a field name which is a string, such as 'services.2DA.lowLevelServices.EXD'. I am accessing them like so:

```
           valueGetter: function getTotal2DA(params) {
                return params.data.services['2DA'].lowLevelServices.EXD +
                params.data.services['2DA'].lowLevelServices['2DA'] +
                params.data.services['2DA'].lowLevelServices.TBX +
                params.data.services['2DA'].lowLevelServices.EXL +
                params.data.services['2DA'].lowLevelServices['2DM'];
            }
```

I've also tried calling them like:

```
params.data.services['2DA.lowLevelServices.2DA']
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please include an example of what the `params` data hierarchy actually looks like.

Comment: Additionally, your 2nd example is invalid syntax. The string used in the square brackets is the name of the attribute, not a path notation.